# Starting Chrome on macOS from the Finder with extra command line parameters

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I want to stuff remote debugging and other esoteric dev-only only parameters to the Chrome application when it starts but I want it to be always there, including when I click on the app icon.

E.g.:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

How do I pass these command line parameters to the app directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an automator application with as shell task. Customized the icon and replaced Chrome.app with the new app in the dock.

I am still looking for a way to change the settings in Chrome so it can connect with remote debugger "on-demand" for specific tasks (not everything as it is set now) but that doesn't seem to be possible at this time. The VSCode folks have apparently solicited the Chrome team to provide this functionality. Stay tuned...